# How to avoid 'save module configuration' after created menu path in hook_menu ? in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, menu

In Drupal, once created new menu path in module we need to save configuration to make it work. How to avoid this step as I'm having multi-site and number of sites is more than 100 sharing common folder.
So if I create a new menu path in a module, I need to login to admin and save module configuration for all sites. How to avoid this step ?

Answer (score 0):

couple ideas for this issue:
1) use drush command
2) Implement cron hook
3)

Answer (score 0):

I think drush is the best option here.
Download and install it. I would give you information but it depends on Drupal version and operating system, so probably best to search drush.
Then you can use it to cache clear every site, see here for how:
http://codedrop.com.au/blog/run-drush-commands-all-sites-drupal-multi-site